# Shiny app: Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0

Tags: r, shiny

```
#install.packages("shinythemes")
#install.packages("shinyjs")
install.packages("DT")
install.packages("reshape2")

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(reshape2)

data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Kanchan/Desktop/timeforcompletion.csv")


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dat <- reactive ({

    row1 <- row.names (data[data$Chromosomes == input$select & 
                              data$Data.per.chromosomes == input$select1 &
                              data$CPU.worker == input$select2,])
    row1 <- as.numeric(row1)
    out1 <- data$Num.of.workers[row1]
    out2 <- data$Time.to.complete..Mins.[row1]



    val <- data.frame(Name = c("Num of workers","Time.to.complete..Mins." ), Value = c(out1,out2)
                      ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    #require(reshape2)
    #melt(val)
    return(val)

  })

  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(dat())


}


ui <- fluidPage( theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
                 shinyjs::inlineCSS(list(body = "color:DarkBlue")),
                 titlePanel("WQ-MAKER"),

                 sidebarLayout(

                   sidebarPanel(
                     "Sidebar"
                   ), #endsidebarpanel

                   mainPanel(

                     selectInput("select", label = h3("Chromosomes"), 
                                 choices = list("12" = 1, "24" = 2), 
                                 selected = 1),
                     selectInput("select1", label = h3("Data per chromosomes"), 
                                 choices = list("100000" = 1, "200000" = 2, "1000000" = 3), 
                                 selected = 1),
                     selectInput("select2", label = h3("CPU per worker"), 
                                 choices = list("4" = 1), 
                                 selected = 1),
                     #textOutput("text1")
                     hr(),
                     DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")

                   )#end mainpanel
                 )# end sidebarlayout
)



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The input dataset looks like this:

```
Chromosomes Data per chromosomes    CPU/worker  Num of workers  Time to complete (Mins)          
12          100000                  4           3               16.8333
24          100000                  4           3               23.4167
12          200000                  4           3               23.1333
12          1000000                 4           3               54.7667
12          1000000                 4           7               17.5444
```

I understand that the problem is with output$mytable. Please help me rectify the code to return an output that displays 2 values.

Num of workers : xxx
Time to completion : xxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem seems to be that your `dat` function is filtering the data frame by value, but your `selectInput` choices are tied to arbitrary indices that don't mean anything with respect to the original `data`.  Lose the `= 1`, `= 2`, etc. and the application almost works.

```
                 selectInput("select", label = h3("Chromosomes"), 
                             choices = list("12", "24"), 
                             selected = 1),
                 selectInput("select1", label = h3("Data per chromosomes"), 
                             choices = list("100000", "200000", "1000000"), 
                             selected = 1),
                 selectInput("select2", label = h3("CPU per worker"), 
                             choices = list("4"), 
                             selected = 1),
```

Next you need the `dat` function to return NULL if no data values are returned.

```
    if (length(row1)==0)
      return(NULL)
```

Now you should see a data frame printed with values, but at this point you probably need to tweak the output to look more like what you originally wanted.  You may also want the app to print a friendly message if no values matched the selection criteria.  Both are left as an exercise to the reader.  :)

Comment: BTW, here's a good article on debugging Shiny apps.  FYI, I used plain old `cat()` to debug this one.  http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks T.J :) The app works just fine now, and the debugging tips article is quite cool.

Comment: @KanchanSonthalia Great!  In that case, please click the green check mark to the left of this answer to accept it, and we both get reputation points.